# Facebook SDK 3.5, someone who made it to work?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.0

-

Hi.

Is there someone out there that have done the Facebook SDK 3.5.2 to work with their project?

> 1. Startup your app.
> 2. You see the Facebook login button.
> 3. Click on it, write in your mail/password and done.
> 4. When pressed done/finish, you go to a new Activity/Fragment there your app would be and the logout button would be.

I have ofcourse looked at the Facebook Developer site, followed their tutorials, but many of them are deprecated and old. Some not even working, the samples in the SDK would not work either. This is all I want, a finished java-class that someone can share with me, so I just can copy-paste it and start on my project.

Some tutorials, they talk about the "app_id" and "ApplicationId" connected to the app_id, while some other dont have the keyHash, app_secret code and so on. I want ofcourse that my app would work on different phones & tablets, and yes, I have done the keytool and have the keyhash and so on, All I need is a working file. I can put in my keyhash, app_id, applicationId and so on, but its the rest I need.

Thank you.

P.S. Dont give link back to Facebook Developers site, I already vacuumed their site with no luck, so please, just paste example code.. and not from the Facebook Developer site, because theirs are deprecated and old.

Comment: I don't think the code explained in facebook developers is deprecated.Download the sample apps from facebook developers site.They have explained each and everything clearly. Compared to older version,using the newer version of facebook SDK is very easy.Check properly!

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/ : in this link samples import details given. see point number 3 and 4 for sample project. please read the doc in details. you will get all the things you required. it has best explanation tutorial. best of luck.

Comment: @AbhishekV @RipalTamboli They are deprecated.
In this link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/ You will find this line of code.

// make request to the /me API
                `Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                        new Request.GraphUserCallback() {`

And that is deprecated. So its old. I followed the tutorials on that page, and yes, I imported the samples like they said. Still, deprecated, old and not useful.

So, back to my original question. Someone who got a working class file that works? And are not deprecated? Who wants to share it?

Comment: And guys, I wrote in my original question that I dont need the link to the Facebook Developer site, that I vacuumed it and it didnt work, was deprecated, old and the samples not working.. And yet, you guys link me back to that horrible page. Thats not funny :)